# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' and TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable

Tags: django, database, web, backend, angular-fullstack

I tried the previous fixes in other tutorials but they didn't work. Here's what I have:

```
...
from models import Tutorial #crashes
from backend.restApis.tutorials.serializers import TutorialSerializer


@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def tutorial_list(request):
  # GET list of tutorials, POST a new tutorial, DELETE all tutorials
  if request.method == 'GET':
    tutorials = Tutorial.objects.all()
    title = request.GET.get('title', None)

    if title is not None:
      tutorials = tutorials.filter(title__icontains=title)

    tutorials_serializer = TutorialSerializer(tutorials, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(tutorials_serializer.data, safe=False)
...
```

I have tried renaming the reference but it doesn't work, here's the file structure
[Project File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inDEi.png)

I am new to django and appreciate any help !

Comment: `from .models import Tutorial`? (note the `.`) Where exactly are you trying to import this? (you never mention that) Or you can specify the full path so `from tutorials.models import Tutorial`

Answer (score 1):

since models ,serializers and views are in the same level you can make call like this:

```
from .models import Tutorial
from .serializers import TutorialSerializer
```

Comment: according to your structure ,that should work